# Change button color and making it active when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like that when I click on one of the two buttons, it changes color and make it "active".
And because it's Gender buttons (M, F), that only one of the two can be selected.

[image: Picture of my form]

```
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="homme" type="button">Homme</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="femme" type="button">Femme</button>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomcomplet" placeholder="Nom complet">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Can you add code in question? So that we can see where its breaking.

Comment: How are you trying to achieve this on js?

Comment: "*...because it's Gender buttons (M, F), ...only one of the two can be selected.*" - you might want to check this assumption against those of your clients, 'gender' is not necessarily the binary choice it once was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this javascript to your file

```
let homme = document.getElementById("homme");
let femme = document.getElementById("femme");
homme.addEventListener("click", function(){
    homme.classList.add("active");
    femme.classList.remove("active");
});
femme.addEventListener("click", function(){
    femme.classList.add("active");
    homme.classList.remove("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you try the pseudo `:active` of `:focus` in the class or tag to apply the color.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Also, with JS you can add and remove or toggle a class called active with styles:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

A example with ClassName:

- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp

Kind regards